# Import a ts file to another ts file using es6 syntax without transpiler

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

suppose i have a ts file under folder folder1
folder1->apptest.ts
in this file i am writing import * as chai from "chai" 
if chai.js is not in same folder means folder1 it is throwing error module cannot find
if i am copying chai.js to folder1 then error gone
Can we import file which is in another folder without using any transpiler

Comment: Have you installed `chai`? Try installing with `npm install chai` and typescript will figure out the module inside `node_modules` folder.

Comment: i am not following node_modules structure inthis,i am integrating chai with msbuild.but the point here is not related to chai,i am saying any ts file or js file suppose sample.js to use in apptest.ts

Comment: let me describe you my folder structure  in file explorer **--
src->client.sln->something.csproj->app.ts 
and my test project is like **--
src-client.sln->test.csproj->apptest.ts
my app.ts have a method Showname(name:string) and i want to use it
so in this scenario i am importing app.ts in apptest.ts like import * as Name from "app" 
but in this case i am getting error cannot find module app
and i have exported app as module.
 if i am copying the app.js file of app.ts to apptest.ts folder then error getting resolved.

Comment: No, you cannot use typescript without a transpiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exact path in apptest.ts:

```
import Showname from '/src/client.sln/something.csproj/app';
```

But you have to remember that typescript will be compiled into JS. So compiled file "app.js" must be in the same folder as ts file`(/src/client.sln/something.csproj/`). If you use outDir compile option, you can use relative path like `import x from '../../something.csproj'`.

But more correct way of doing it: is to use app.ts as a module (see `npm link` or `npm publish` documentation)

Comment: Is there any way to achieve it through typings??

Comment: No, since when JS will be generated, there will be no typings (in run time).

Comment: my error is in compile time,so i think tsc by default search for declaration files in Typings folder.